# Search column name with multiple conditions pandas

Tags: python-3.x

I have a query to retrieve all columns with the name date in them as below

```py
date_raw_cols = [col for col in df_raw.columns if 'date' in col]
```

That is also picking up columns with `updated` which I want to exclude. I've also tried a regex filter as below with same problem of returning `updated`

```py
df_dates = df_raw.filter(regex='date', axis='columns')
```

How do I combine conditions to filter column names. i.e.

Where column name is date but not update, but could be `date1`, `_date`, `date_`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of searching for 'date' in a column name, you can be more explicit:

```
# Assume example df_raw

>>> df_raw 
   date  date1  prev_date  update
0     1      2          3     200
1     4      2          5     300
2     5      5          3     100


>>> date_raw_cols = [col for col in df_raw.columns if col == 'date']
>>> print(date_raw_cols)

['date']
```

EDIT: If your question fully covers your data at hand, you can add an extra condition in the list comprehension with `len() < 6`, which will only grab column names with number of characters less than 6. This way you don't have to explicitly deal with underscores or digits.

```
>>> df_raw

   date  date1  prev_date  update _date date_
0     1      2          3     200     a     g
1     4      2          5     300     s     h
2     5      5          3     100     v     a

>>> date_raw_cols = [col for col in df_raw.columns if 'date' in col and len(col) < 6]
>>> print(date_raw_cols)

['date', 'date1', '_date', 'date_']
```

Comment: But this wouldn't return columns that have 'date' in the column name as a substring.

Comment: exactly. Isn't this the ask? "Where column name is date but not update", i.e. only the 'date' column names?

Comment: I guess the question leaves room for interpretation. Let's wait for OP's response.

Comment: Thanks both, in your example dataset I'd want to return all columns except frpm update

Comment: What if there was a column called "following_date" or "upcoming_date", would you want those? Can you be a bit more specific as your instructions are not exhaustive I believe.

Comment: Thanks, yes. I've editted the question to include further examples

Answer (score 0):

Try following regex:

```
\b(\w*(?=[^a-z]date)|(?=date[^a-z]))\w*\b
```

It will find all words that contain "date" which are bounded with numbers or punctuation marks:

```
re.findall(r'\b\w*(?=[^a-z]date)\w*\b|\b(?=date[^a-z])\w*\b', 
         'date1 date date_1 update new_date 234_date 33date datetime ')

['date1', '', 'date', '', 'date_1', 'new_date', '234_date', '33date', '']
```